How can I make a card in PowerBI that shows selected value possible from different columns?
I am making a PowerBI drill through page and I want to have a card that shows whatever the user selected to drill through.
I’m having a difficult time because the drill through page can be navigated to by clicking values from multiple possible columns.
For example, it can be navigated to by drilling through on Orange juice from the Drinks column, but also from Barbecue from the Food column. Both are in different visuals in the main report page.
Is there a measure or anything I can make so that there is a card at the top of the drill through page that will show whatever I clicked to get to that page? If not, do you have any tips for how I can make it easy for the end user to see exactly what they clicked?
TY in advance!
I have tried nested SelectedValue measures but they result in blank if the drill through clicked is
not the first column im the measure.
I am hoping for the card to be able to show one value from whatever of the possible columns it pulled from.

In a measure you can create a SELECTEDVALUE for each possible column. Then check each one for data to display:
Measure = 
VAR Category1 = SELECTEDVALUE('Product'[Product])
VAR Category2 = SELECTEDVALUE('Store'[Store])

VAR output = SWITCH(TRUE()
,Category1 <> BLANK(), Category1
,Category2 <> BLANK(), Category2
,BLANK()
)

return output


Thanks, this works for the most part but not fully.
I have another column Member (Category1) with values [Chris], [Mary], [Daniel], etc.
If Drinks (Category2) is orange juice but only Chris drank orange juice, the card ends up showing “Chris” even though it was Orange juice that was selected to drill through.
Any idea how to go about this so that the card correctly shows orange juice instead of Chris? I figured I could make Drinks category1 and Members Category2 but this only seems like a bandaid solution for this specific scenario.
Hoping for further guidance if this is possible!

So you drill down into Member, then drill through on Drinks?
